# IdMemberMap is null using "Representation Serialization Options"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

Using MongoDB I want to keep my model as clean as possible so I decided to follow this approach: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial#CSharpDriverSerializationTutorial-RepresentationSerializationOptions

I have a class like:

```
public class Person
{        
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {

    }
    public Person(string name)
    {            
        this.Name = name;            
    }
}
```

And inside application_start I have

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Person>(x =>
{
   x.AutoMap();
   x.IdMemberMap.SetRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId);
});
```

But when it run I get a null reference exception on the `IdMemberMap`. Can someone please tell me if something is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is borderline to being a bug in the C# driver. Turns out IdMemberMap is not defined until the class map is "frozen", for reasons having to do with class hierarchies in which the Id might actually be defined in a base class. One way to work around this is:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Person>(cm => {
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.Freeze();
    cm.IdMemberMap.SetRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId);
});
```

Another way to work around is to use GetMemberMap instead of IdMemberMap:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Person>(cm => {
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.Id).SetRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId);
});
```

Comment: Not working. If I use **Freeze**, I got an exception (_has been frozen and no further changes are allowed_). And if I use the other way, ID is not set at all. Here is the working solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22509866/1480391

Comment: It is now looking like `SetRepresentation` is missing from the library altogether...

Comment: Not working for me. If `Id` is defined in a base class this woks for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16425315/498298 . Map each level of hierarchie separately.

Answer (score 0):

### Set an ID generator manually

It's missing in the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/#representationserializationoptions) but you need to manually set an ID generator:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Person>(cm =>
{
  cm.AutoMap();
  cm.IdMemberMap.SetRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId);
  cm.IdMemberMap.SetIdGenerator(StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance);
}
```

Source: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongodb-user/_pjCDXZ9hOk/9N23ARe0_rgJ