# MongoDb registering class map

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have the following code. I want MiscellaneousData to override an abstract MiscellaneousDataBase. However the IdMemberMap always comes up null.

Using a standalone 'normal' class works.

```
if (!BsonClassMap.IsClassMapRegistered(typeof(MiscellaneousData)))
{
    BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MiscellaneousData>(cm =>
    {
        cm.AutoMap();
        cm.SetIdMember(cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.Key));
        cm.IdMemberMap.SetIdGenerator(StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance);
    });
}
```

Here is the miscellaneous data and its base - reduced down for clarity:

```
public abstract class MiscellaneousDataBase
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public abstract string Key { get; set; }
}

public class MiscellaneousData : MiscellaneousDataBase
{
    public override string Key { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating class maps you map each member at the level at which it is declared, so you need to map MiscellaneousDataBase and MiscellaneousData separately.

Below is some sample code showing how to map each class separately (I added an X property to the subclass so there would be something to map at that level).

Using these classes:

```
public abstract class MiscellaneousDataBase
{
    public abstract string Key { get; set; }
}

public class MiscellaneousData : MiscellaneousDataBase
{
    public override string Key { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; }
}
```

try mapping them like this:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MiscellaneousDataBase>(cm =>
{
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.SetIdMember(cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.Key));
    cm.IdMemberMap.SetIdGenerator(StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance);
});

BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MiscellaneousData>(cm =>
{
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.X).SetElementName("x");
});
```